# Groupby Pandas to group by SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I've got a dataframe and am currently using python to do the bulk of my calculations, but SQL would be faster given hundred million of rows. My code below groups put and calls by expiration and strike. We look at highest mid price of each group and take the difference. After that we look for the minimum difference. Python code would look like this:

```
df['Price'] = (df['Bid'].values + df['Ask'].values) / 2
df['Maturity'] = (df['Expiration'] - df['DataDate']).dt.days / 365
```

df output:

```
       UnderlyingSymbol  UnderlyingPrice  Type Expiration   DataDate  Strike  \
686098              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04 2018-09-04   150.0   
686100              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04 2018-09-04   155.0   
686102              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04 2018-09-04   160.0   
686104              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04 2018-09-04   165.0   
686106              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04 2018-09-04   170.0   
                ...              ...   ...        ...        ...     ...   
691381              SPY       289.839996   put 2020-12-18 2018-09-04   400.0   
691382              SPY       289.839996  call 2020-12-18 2018-09-04   405.0   
691383              SPY       289.839996   put 2020-12-18 2018-09-04   405.0   
691384              SPY       289.839996  call 2020-12-18 2018-09-04   410.0   
691385              SPY       289.839996   put 2020-12-18 2018-09-04   410.0   

              Last         Bid         Ask       Price  Maturity  
686098  136.710007  139.860001  140.119995  139.989990  0.000000  
686100  132.520004  134.850006  135.119995  134.985001  0.000000  
686102  127.519997  129.860001  130.119995  129.989990  0.000000  
686104  120.349998  124.779999  125.220001  125.000000  0.000000  
686106  115.389999  119.779999  120.220001  120.000000  0.000000  
           ...         ...         ...         ...       ...  
691381  128.729996  110.260002  111.660004  110.960007  2.290411  
691382    0.850000    0.740000    0.900000    0.820000  2.290411  
691383  134.089996  115.239998  116.190002  115.714996  2.290411  
691384    0.690000    0.640000    0.800000    0.720000  2.290411  
691385  128.550003  120.230003  121.639999  120.934998  2.290411
```

after this we group by expiration and strike, and look at the highest mid price of each group.

```
c = df[df.Type == 'call'].groupby(['Expiration','Strike'])['Price'].first()
p = df[df.Type == 'put'].groupby(['Expiration','Strike'])['Price'].first()
df = df.join((c - p).rename('CP_diff'), on=['Expiration','Strike'])

df = df[~df.CP_diff.isna()]
df['Forward'] = df['CP_diff'].values + df['Strike']
```

c output:

```
 Expiration  Strike
2018-09-04  150.0     139.989990
            155.0     134.985001
            160.0     129.989990
            165.0     125.000000
            170.0     120.000000

2020-12-18  390.0       1.290000
            395.0       1.095000
            400.0       0.965000
            405.0       0.820000
            410.0       0.720000
```

after that we take the minimum price difference of each group and update our dataframe accordingly

```
minimum_difference = df.loc[df.groupby("Expiration")["CP_diff"].idxmin().values]
minimum_difference = minimum_difference[['Forward', 'Expiration']].set_index("Expiration")
df = df.set_index("Expiration")
df.update(minimum_difference)
```

minimum_difference output:

```
Forward
Expiration            
2018-09-04  289.975006
2018-09-05  289.980011
2018-09-07  289.989990
2018-09-10  289.984985
2018-09-12  289.984985
2018-09-14  289.984985
2018-09-17  289.984985
```

and finally df output:

```
           UnderlyingSymbol  UnderlyingPrice  Type   DataDate  Strike  \
Expiration                                                              
2018-09-04              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04   290.0   
2018-09-04              SPY       289.839996   put 2018-09-04   290.0   
2018-09-05              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04   270.0   
2018-09-05              SPY       289.839996   put 2018-09-04   270.0   
2018-09-05              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04   270.5   
                    ...              ...   ...        ...     ...   
2020-12-18              SPY       289.839996   put 2018-09-04   400.0   
2020-12-18              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04   405.0   
2020-12-18              SPY       289.839996   put 2018-09-04   405.0   
2020-12-18              SPY       289.839996  call 2018-09-04   410.0   
2020-12-18              SPY       289.839996   put 2018-09-04   410.0   

                  Last         Bid         Ask       Price  Maturity  \
Expiration                                                             
2018-09-04    0.040000    0.030000    0.040000    0.035000  0.000000   
2018-09-04    0.050000    0.050000    0.070000    0.060000  0.000000   
2018-09-05    0.000000   19.910000   20.080000   19.994999  0.002740   
2018-09-05    0.010000    0.010000    0.020000    0.015000  0.002740   
2018-09-05   19.090000   19.410000   19.580000   19.494999  0.002740   
               ...         ...         ...         ...       ...   
2020-12-18  128.729996  110.260002  111.660004  110.960007  2.290411   
2020-12-18    0.850000    0.740000    0.900000    0.820000  2.290411   
2020-12-18  134.089996  115.239998  116.190002  115.714996  2.290411   
2020-12-18    0.690000    0.640000    0.800000    0.720000  2.290411   
2020-12-18  128.550003  120.230003  121.639999  120.934998  2.290411   

               Forward  
Expiration              
2018-09-04  289.975006  
2018-09-04  289.975006  
2018-09-05  289.980011  
2018-09-05  289.980011  
2018-09-05  289.980011
```

How could I achieve the same with SQL? My try would be as follows:

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT df.datadate,df.expiration,df.type,(df.ask+df.bid)/2 as mid, 
        df.type,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY df.expiration, df.type, df.datadate
                                 ORDER BY (df.ask+od.bid)/2 DESC) AS rk
      FROM option_data df
where od.Underlyingsymbol = 'SPY')

SELECT  s.*
FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk = 1
```

Am I right, to have calculated python variable p and c with above query? This would be my first more complex SQL query and I am trying to get some examples which I could build on.

Comment: For those of us who don't speak panda fluently, please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text to clarify your requirement.

Comment: done, but it looks quite confusing now?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Recall no two SQL dialects are the same. Please tag.

Comment: @Hekri . . . Instead of explaining the step-by-step process of what you are doing in Pandas, it would be better to show sample data, your desired results, and explain the rules that you want to implement in SQL.